# Why doesn't xcode let me create an IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add an outlet for a button, but when I control drag the button into the viewController class, it only allows me to create an action. In the screenshot you can see that the connection type is grayed out and stuck on action. Why isnt it letting me add an outlet? this same issue happens for every object like labels and text fields.

[image: screenshot of my editor for context]

Comment: You need to drag the reference to the source file, inside the class itself. Alternatively you can define an @IBOutlet in your ViewController and then drag from that to the label/button to wire it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because you need to connect the storyboard vc to the file.

Click on the storyboard vc -> Click tab on right -> Enter name of view controller file into Class (Where it is highlighted in the image)

[image]